# Centering Checkbox in Table

Tags: html

I'm using an MDBootstrap Custom checkbox and want to display it in a table cell for every foreach loop in Razor. The foreach doesn't really matter though, but I can't get the checkbox to center horizontally. A normal Checkbox input works fine, but when I use the custom Checkbox from bootstrap, it's not aligned to center anymore. This is my HTML with custom checkbox.

```
 <td style="text-align:center;padding:0Px; vertical-align:middle;">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
             <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked">
             <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked"></label>
      </div>
</td>
```

This is the normal checkbox that works

```
<input type="checkbox" >
```

On the following picture you can see both the custom and standard checkbox. The one without the warning background is the one I would want centered.

[image]

Comment: Could you add this to a fiddle?

Comment: Can't recreate it according to the provided information. Centers perfectly when I do it. Please provide more information, specifically your CSS, preferably in a fiddle of some sort.

Comment: There isnt any added css. I only used inline css in this example. Must be a parent element that causes the issue then.

Comment: By "css" I don't refer to only what is targeting the checkbox itself. Obviously there is some styling applied otherwise you wouldn't have the classes `.custom-control` and `.custom-checkbox` I would presume.

Comment: The point being; you need to provide enough information for us to recreate exactly what you posted an image of.

Comment: oh those classes are from an online library as mentioned. Those arent classes i made css styling for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add custom css for MDBootstrap Custom checkbox like this:

```css
.custom-control-label::before, .custom-control-label::after {
  left: -1.25rem !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.3/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;padding:0Px; vertical-align:middle; width: 50px; height: 50px">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked"></label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;padding:0Px; vertical-align:middle; width: 50px; height: 50px">
            <input type="checkbox" >
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```